# Somebody guide me to implement tag subscription plugin. 

Tags: subscription

I would like to implement tag subscription and follow/nofollow for registered users.

I mean when the user goto tag page, left side widget should show subscribe/unsubscribe button.

And when the user goto author page, left side widget should show follow/nofollow button.

Front page posts should have two other tabs called "subscribed" and "following".

When the user click `subscribed tab` it should show the posts which contains user subscribed tags. Likewise `following tab` should only show user following author posts.

Is there any readymade plugin available???
If not can i use existing plugins like subscriber2 to implement this feature.

What are the steps? I should store the tag and author id in the database right?

PS: I don't want you to code my plugin. This is my first wordpress plugin which requires database related work. So i just wanna understand how the database works. I just want to know whether i should create a new table or can i use existing meta tables to implement this feature.
If i can use existing table which table i should use to store tag id and author id.

Comment: @Viruthagirl It would be best to rephrase your question to be more specific. Instead of asking someone to do the work for you, you should try implementing the concept yourself and use this forum if you get stumped. The community is all about helping, but the way your question comes across is that you want someone to do all the work for you. A simple edit might get you more answers. :)

Comment: Ok i'm not sure how to rephrase this question. I don't want stackexchange to do the job for me. This is my first plugin which requires database related work. I just want the procedure. I mean like which table i should use to store the value..etc..

Comment: I'll make the edit for you. :)

Comment: Much better. :)

Comment: Sorry, but this question is still **far** too vague. Voted to close as "not a real question".

Comment: @ChipBennett Oh i'm sorry. I didn't mean to ask stupid questions. Brian posted a good answer and its definitely worth for the time i spent to type the question. You can go ahead and close it

Comment: "*Stupid*" is not the correct term. :) I would go with "*not focused enough*". It's not *stupid*; it's just too broadly scoped, and could be broken down into multiple questions. For example, a great example might be "*Where/how do I create and store custom user meta data?*"

Comment: @ChipBennett Ah.. got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this is:

- Create several [AJAX calls](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) using the nopriv hook bound to the subscribe/follow button clicks.
- Within the PHP callback functions, I would insert value of the tag or the followed user into the logged-in user's meta using `add_user_meta`, `get_user_meta`, `delete_user_meta`.
- Lastly, I would create a conditional function to use in your templates that pulls down the user meta, checks the current tags or users and then return a bool value so you can render the proper state of your buttons.

The AJAX PHP callback would use something like the following:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$tags = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'tag_subscription');
if(in_array($tag_slug, $tags))
    //do something
else
    add_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'tag_subscription', $tag_slug, false);
```

To remove an element from the user meta array, you would do the following:

```
delete_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'tag_subscription', $tag_slug);
```

The conditional template tag would look like this in your template:

```
if(is_user_subscribed()){
     //display this state of the button
}
else{
     //display another state of the button
}
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks Brian, You posted a great answer and definitely it will help me.

Comment: Glad to help you!